# QGIS 3.4.2 - timemanager plugin - NetCDF - attribute

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, netcdf, timemanager

When updating QGIS from version 2.18 to 3.4.2
my NetCDF files are no longer loading in the timemanager plugin

My time variable in the NetCDF file has the following attribute

```
double time(time) ;
    time:long_name = "time" ;
    time:standard_name = "time" ;
    time:units = "seconds since 1970-1-1" ;
```

I have the following message on the log message

```
INFO    Could not guess timestamp in raster filename. Cause 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
WARNING    Could not import netcdftime. Using fallback computation
```

I try adding a start attribute without success.
Where could I find information on the timemanager input requirement for NetCDF file?

Comment: Seems like the plugin are looking for a nonexistent layer. Can you remove layers from plugin and add it again? There are only one ticket open for netCDF files in the [TimeManager github](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues?q=netcdf), but even the object is recognized. Your time field format seems to be ok.

Comment: at the end the raster layer is not added to the timemanager list of layers. I also have a warning when asking to use the option 'netcdf file' that I reported above in the main post.

Comment: is this possible to have access to a netcdf file that is known to load correctly in timemanager.

Comment: You can try with the [sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwc-5JFVTnfIb3E2LVR4NjE0SjA/view) provided for the [workshop in Nodebo](https://anitagraser.com/2015/05/22/time-manager-workshop-at-qgis2015/). I can not find any reference of the performance of those files in QGIS 3.4.2

Comment: I tried unsuccessfully to load the netcdf files of Example_Cloud-rasters in the timemanager (version 3.0.1). I have the same message as reported above. I installed qgis v3.4.2 from the debian repository.

Comment: I was able to open the _rasters-final.qgs_ project and save it as a QGIS 3.4.2 project. I re-opened it and the sequence works well, but when I tried to see the _Settings_ of the plugin, it returned the error: `AttributeError: 'TimeRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'resetSubsetString'` , wich is reported in [this open issue](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/256). It seems that theTimeManager plugin is not working with netCDF layers in QGIS 3.4.2 yet.

Comment: I opened a ticket [here](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/273). thanks for the help.